# How many unequivalent Seifert surfaces appear in a AdS/CFT extension?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, ads-cft, topology

When introducing the 't Hooft diagrams from Feynman diagrams on a torus has there been a classification in terms of knots and [Seifert surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface)?